# How can a DAO benefit the scalability of a system?

Tags: java, scalability, dao

maybe this is not a technical question but I bet here are many experienced developers that can help me answering that

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DAO layer is essentially an abstraction like Sajit says. However I disagree with his interpretation. The point of abstracting  something to achieve a goal - usually the simplification of some more complex use case.

You could easily create a DAO layer that also provides more functionality than simply doing application entity - data entity mapping. It could provide caching, optimisation, translation, resiliency etc. So There is no reason why it could not offer the ability to better scale your application.

Ultimately is depends on terms - what does scaling mean to your application? More/faster ??? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Dao is typically used to abstract away the implementation details of the database in an application and has nothing to do with scalability.

Answer (score 1):

The DAO (Data Access Object) is used to provide a layer of abstraction over the database. It tends to have methods which in turn eventually open connections and execute queries and/or stored procedure.

I think that when it comes to the scalability issue, you need to watch out for 1 major thing in a DAO: Connection management. If you are using some third party library, maybe something along the lines of [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) you will *most likely* have to worry less about connections since these are managed by the library itself.

On the other hand, if you implement everything yourself you will need to make sure that you open the connection at the last moment possible and release it at the first possible moment. Having a DAO which hogs connections will eventually limit how will your application scale.

Lastly, in some cases, the DAO passes direct queries to the database. You will need to keep an eye on how you build these queries to make sure that they do not involve any unneeded processing.

Answer (score 0):

In really simple words, You really can't make a scalable application if everything is tied up. DAO is just another layer which helps you deals with the Data Access Logic. This way you know where you can find your dynamic sql and stuff and can enhance and maintain it.